# Label does not display on postback?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have an `asp:Label` on a page. When I do a post back via a button click, the label does not show.  It shows in some cases such as the following:

```
if(ddlStatus.SelectedValue == "-1")
   lblMessage.Text = "Select Status";
```

But it does not show in this case:

```
lblMessage.Text = SendRequest();

SaveRequest();
```

I can see the value when debugging, it just doesn't appear on the page.

`<span id="PageBody_PageBody_lblMessage" style="color:Red;font-size:Large;"></span>`

Comment: Do you have some code in Page_Load event which set value to this textbox ?

Comment: The label is not set in Page_Load

Comment: Use the inspection tools in IE, firefox, or chrome, and try to find the label, see what the HTML looks like, and post it here.  Nothing in-built to the label removes text...

Comment: @BrianMains, I posted the HTML that is generated.

Comment: In which event is this code used: `lblMessage.Text = SendRequest();`? Also verify that the text set is not cleared later in another event. If you still have issue with this, override `Render` method of `Page` class (don't change it, just call the base `Render` method), put a breakpoint in there and verify if you can see the text in the control with debugger.

Comment: you probably checked that, but did you verify that SendRequest not returns empty string ? If so what exactly that method returns ?

Answer (score 0):

Does SendRequest() return a string, or allow you to do something like SendRequest().toString(); ?

Sounds sort of like it doesnt recognize the content attempting to be placed into the labe to me.

Comment: SendRequest returns a string.

Answer (score 0):

The only possible problems are:

- The method is returning either an empty string.
- Some piece of code is wiping out the originally set value.  Override OnPreRender, and check the label's Text property to verify.

If text is there, it renders it, is what Telerik's JustDecompile is telling me when I'm looking into what the Label does.

Comment: I noticed the Label gets cleared out during PreRender.  I am not sure which code could be wiping it out. I have a method that sets the variable if there is an error and then when PreRender is called, the label is cleared.  All the method does is set the label and return false if there was an error, true if not.

Comment: @Xaisoft How does the `SendRequest()` method return true or false, if it's assigning to the Text of the label?  This would result in a compile error... is the code snippet above correct?

Comment: @Xaisoft Interesting about PreRender... Label does not have any code that runs on PreRender, so something somewhere must be causing the problem...

Comment: I don't see where I put SendRequest returns a bool?  It returns a string.

Comment: @Xaisoft here:  All the method does is set the label and return *false* if there was an error, *true* if not, not sure how this factored in?

Comment: Ah, I had it like that at first, but now it just returns a string which is the error message.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is the best way, but what I decided to do is declare global variable to hold the error message, I called it `response` for example, then in the `PreRender` method which I override, after it calls it's base, I set the `lblMessage.Text = response` and this displays the label.